# Elastisearch how to get only BUCKETS JSON DATA and set in JQUERY

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, search, elasticsearch

When I use POSTGRES, the JSON results are in this format.

```
["Label": "2016-11-24", "value": "200", "getname": "hem"
{"Label": "2016-11-23", "value": "550", "getname": "hem"
{"Label": "2016-11-22", "value": "400", "getname": "rain"
{"Label": "2016-11-21", "value": "310", "getname": "rain"},
{"Label": "2016-11-19", "value": "260", "getname": "rait"}]
```

However when I use Elasticsearch with aggregation the results are in this format

```
{
    "Total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
}, "hits": {
    "total": 5862557,
    "max_score ": " Hits ": []
}, " aggregations ": {
    " entradas ": {
        " buckets ": [{
                " key_as_string ": " 2016-01-01 ",
                " key ": 1451606400000,
                " doc_count ",
                "Key_as_string": "2016-02-01",
                "key": 1454284800000,
                "doc_count": 350358,
                "entries": {
                    "value": 997924
                }
            }, {
                "Key_as_string": "2016-03-01",
                "key": 1456790400000,
                "doc_count": 377480,
                -01 ",
                " key ": 1459468800000,
                " doc_count ": 403180, " entradas ": {
                    " value ": 1291767
                }
            }, {
                " key_as_string ": 1462060800000,
                " doc_count ",
                " Doc_count ": 438432,
                " entradas ": {
                    " value ": {
                        " value ": 1518590
                    }
                }, {
                    " key_as_string ": " 2016 - 07 - 01 ",
                    " key ": 1467331200000,
                    " doc_count ": 548238,
                    " entradas ": {
                        " value ": 1703686
                    }
                }, {
                    " key_as_string ": " 2016 - 07 - 01 - 08 - 01 ",
                    " key ": 1470009600000,
                    " doc_count ": 670678,
                    " entradas ": {
                        " value ": 1770877
                    }
                }, {
                    " key_as_string " " Doc_count ": 747192,
                    " entradas ": {
                        " value ": 1630031
                    }
                }, {
                    " key_as_string " " Key_as_string ": " 2016 - 11 - 01 ",
                    " key ": 1477958400000,
                    " doc_count ": 735642,
                    " entradas ": {
                        " value ": 1706073
                    }
                }, {
                    " key_as_string " " 2016 - 12 - 01 ",
                    " key ": 1480550400000,
                    " doc_count ": 64316,
                    " entradas ": {
                        " value ": 37401
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With POSTGRES visualization graph works perfectly.
But with Elasticsearch not.

Someone could help me to change my JQUERY $ .each () value

```
$ .post ('http://get.dev/trending', {
    Min: startDate.format ('{yyyy} - {MM} - {dd}'),
    Max: endDate.format ('{yyyy} - {MM} - {dd}')
}, 
Function (data) {
    Var set = [];
    $ .each (data.hits.hits, function () {
        Set.push ({
            X: this.key_as_string,
            Y: parseInt (this.doc_count, 10)
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: what errors do you have in the console?\

Comment: `set !== Set` ??? Hope you get it?

Comment: the Elasticsearch results is not a valid json

Comment: and `this` belongs to something else and you don't have data in the callback. So in short there are multiple errors.....!

Comment: http://pro.jsonlint.com/ check you have invalid json.

Comment: I have no error,  but no set the value @madalin ivascu

Comment: With elasticsearch I get very well in Json without error quoted top @Jai

Comment: @Jai   set !== Set  no  always

Comment: HELLO! Someone can help me please.